# How to convert .txt files to multiline String in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days, I just cant find a good method to open a .txt file. I need to convert it into a multiline string and set it as a textview. Can someone help me please?

as for the file location, I'm using:

```
String saveLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/My Documents/";
public String title;
public String Ftype = ".txt";

(saveLoc+title+Ftype) //is the file location.
```

I can normally read the data into a file input stream,  but if I try and do anything with it I get loads of errors that wont let my app even run.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String readTxt(){

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("Text File Path Here");

     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     int i;
  try {
   i = inputStream.read();
   while (i != -1)
      {
       byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
       i = inputStream.read();
      }
      inputStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

     return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast!   But I cant use a pre defined location,  the program is opening user created files,  that is why the string 'title' was left empty.  the button that runs the block of code defines the value for title.

Comment: There's no problem with that as well, you can read the file from external storage easily.

Comment: lol how?  sorry, I'm very new to Android and I haven't really been familiar with java for that long.

Comment: thanks,  I can't test it though, because it is defined before the user gives a file location,  is there a way for me to put it inside a method so I can trigger it with a button?  I tried to, but I get a "Incert EnumBody" error... I've never seen that error before.

Comment: Maybe you should take up some basic Java IO lessons before working on Android. Just an advice though !

Answer (score 0):

use Apache Commons IO FileUtils.readLines()

`readLines
public static List readLines(File file,
                     Charset encoding)
                              throws IOException
Reads the contents of a file line by line to a List of Strings. The file is always closed.
Parameters:
file - the file to read, must not be null
encoding - the encoding to use, null means platform default
Returns:
the list of Strings representing each line in the file, never null
Throws:
IOException - in case of an I/O error
Since:
2.3`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException 
{
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
    try {
            FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
            /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
            return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
        }

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally 
    {
           stream.close();
    }
}
```